# Save a canvas image to SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, ajax, image, html5

I have a page where users can paint on it. This area uses `HTML5` canvas.

Now I want put an button for users to send that image to the server.

I know I can do this by ajax in client side and web-method in server side.

How could I combine this? How could I create a web-method in SharePoint and something like this?

Answer (score 0):

First you should serialize your Canvas to a Data Url using: `canvas.toDataURL();`

By doing so, you get the Image as a `dataURL`, which contains the base 64 Encoded Version of the File (usually in PNG Format). The Data is located after the first comma. [Details here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

You can then upload this file using either CSOM or REST.

[See this article for uploading](https://www.itunity.com/article/uploading-files-sharepoint-2013-csom-rest-2891)

Comment: hi. i can`t achieve this. my sharepoint ver is 2010. i can encode image to 64bit but can`t upload it by REST or CSOM

Comment: CSOM also works with SP 2010. What exactly does the error message say?

Comment: I do not have an error. my requirement is a Walkthrough to do it. an example or way  to show me how could save an image from client to share-point server 2010

Comment: So you are asking Harry to do your job?